# Create map object from elements JavaScript add or remove values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have objects

```
let obj1 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange"}
let obj2 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits",name:"Apple"}
let obj3 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} 
let obj4 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Ginger"}....etc
```

I want to create a map from this array expected:

```
{
  "Fruits": [{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": "Fruits",
    "name": "Orange"
  }, {
    "categoryId": 1,
    "category": "Fruits",
    "name": "Apple"
  }],
  "Vegetables": [{
    "categoryId": 2,
    "category": "Vegetables",
    "name": "Onion"
  }, {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "category": "Vegetables",
    "name": "Ginger"
  }]
}
```

I am looking for a function to add to the map one by one

```
addtoMap( obj1);
addtoMap( obj2); 
addtoMap( obj3); 
addtoMap( obj4);....etc
```

Also remove from the map

```
removeFromMap( obj1);
```

I have tried

```
addtoMap(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Will post you updated

Comment: Updated what I tried

Comment: You want to write `setter/getter` but the interface is incorrect. In such case, you will have 3 values: `ObjectToAddRemove`, `KeyToSearch` and `ValueToSet`. Your expected format accepts 2 arguments and during calling you are passing 1. Try to analyse and update the interfaces first and you should be good.

Comment: You say you have tried that code ? that doesn't look like a ' try ' on your specific data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the object exists and add the object in the wanted category. The same goes for deleting an object, until no more objects are in the group. Then the group gets removed as well.

```js
function addToCollection(collection, object) {
    if (!collection[object.category]) {
        collection[object.category] = [object];
        return;
    }
    if (collection[object.category].includes(object)) return;
    collection[object.category].push(object);
}

function removeFromCollection(collection, object) {
    if (!collection[object.category]) return;
    var index = collection[object.category].indexOf(object);
    if (index === -1) return;
    collection[object.category].splice(index, 1);
    if (!collection[object.category].length) delete collection[object.category];
}

var obj1 = { categoryId: 1, category: "Fruits", name:"Orange" },
    obj2 = { categoryId: 1, category: "Fruits", name:"Apple" },
    obj3 = { categoryId: 2, category: "Vegetables", name:"Onion" },
    obj4 = { categoryId: 2, category: "Vegetables", name:"Ginger" },
    collection = {};


addToCollection(collection, obj1);
addToCollection(collection, obj2);
addToCollection(collection, obj3);
addToCollection(collection, obj4);
console.log(collection);
removeFromCollection(collection, obj2);
console.log(collection);
removeFromCollection(collection, obj1);
console.log(collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to fulfill your requirements, but here is a way to do it immutably:

```js
let obj1 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits", name:"Orange"}
let obj2 = { categoryId:1, category:"Fruits",name:"Apple"}
let obj3 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Onion"} 
let obj4 = { categoryId:2, category:"Vegetables", name:"Ginger"}

const add = (map, o) => ({ ...map, [o.category]: [...(map[o.category] || []), o] });
  
const remove = (map, o) => ({ ...map, [o.category]: map[o.category].filter(x => x.name !== o.name) });

let map = {};
map = add(map, obj1);
map = add(map, obj2);
map = add(map, obj3);
map = add(map, obj4);

console.log(JSON.stringify(map));

map = remove(map, obj1);
map = remove(map, obj2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(map));
```